# TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number in time.sleep()

Tags: python

I have a interval time of 30 seconds, which I am adding in my Python script in time.sleep() for 30 seconds.

```
interval="00:00:30"
interval_seconds=interval.split(":",2)
interval_seconds[2]=interval_seconds
print interval_seconds
```

Now I am using this value in my code as:

```
count=2
while(count>0):
    print "inside while"
    time.sleep(float(interval_seconds))
    count=count-1
```

While running I am getting this error:

```
time.sleep(float(interval_seconds))
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number
```

Comment: just flip `interval_seconds[2] = interval_seconds`

Answer (score 3):

```
interval_seconds[2]=interval_seconds
```

It's still a `list` so you can't put a list in `float()` function. You have to take the element that you want to put in `float()`. So in your case solution is;

```
time.sleep(float(interval_seconds[2]))
```

Full code;

```
interval="00:00:30"
interval_seconds=interval.split(":",2)
print interval_seconds

count=2
while(count>0):
    print "inside while"
    time.sleep(float(interval_seconds[2])) 
    count=count-1
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the problem with your code:

```
interval="00:00:30"
# creates a list with all elements describing the time
# you don't need the second argument, as you intend to split on
# all ':'
interval_seconds=interval.split(":",2)
# this does *not* do what you expect.
# it assigns a list to 'interval seconds' list at index 2
interval_seconds[2]=interval_seconds
# now you have nested lists :(
print interval_seconds
```

Try this instead:

```
interval="00:00:30"
# take only third element (index 2)
interval_seconds=interval.split(":")[2]
print interval_seconds
```

This will only take the seconds part.

**Tip:** You may want to use [timedelta](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) to describe a quantity of time here:

```
>>> from datetime import timdelta
>>> interval="00:00:30"
>>> hours, minutes, seconds = interval.split(':')
>>> td = timedelta(hours=int(hours), minutes=int(minutes), secotimedeltands=int(seconds))
>>> td
datetime.timedelta(0, 30)
>>> td.seconds
30
```

You can avoid casting to `int` explicitly multiple times using list comprehension:

```
>>> hours, minutes, seconds = [int(x) for x in interval.split(':')]
```

Or `map`:

```
>>> hours, minutes, seconds = map(int, interval.split(':'))
```

... Just wanted to be clear

Answer (score 2):

i got the mistake i was doing. Instead of previous code it should be

```
interval="00:00:30"
interval_seconds=interval.split(":",2)
interval_seconds=interval_seconds[2]
print interval_seconds
```

and in my code , it should be

```
time.sleep(float(str(interval_seconds)))
```

Then its working fine.`enter code here`

Comment: the `str` is not neccessary because `interval_seconds` already is a string (in this place)

Comment: Check my answer you are trying to convert a string to string again.